# How to get common material shared in multiple plants

Tags: mysql, hana

I have a dataset with "material" and "plant". I want to get the materials that goes into all plants like `10`, `20`, `30` and `40`. I got the answer using `intersect` in MySQL but want to know if there is an optimized way.

My query is:

```
select material from table where plant=10
intersect
select material from table where plant=20
intersect
select material from table where plant=30
intersect
select material from table where plant=40
```

```
material plant
123      10
123      20
123      30
123      40
456      20
```

The query will return "plant 123".

Comment: 'I got the answer like using "intersect" in mysql' - not possible mysql does not have intersect so what rdbms are you using? And what rdbms do you want an answer for?

Comment: i am using HANA and intersect is working.

Comment: i think i just need to to count(*) using group by ..it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to identify the materials, which are available in all plants?

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE test (material varchar(10), plant varchar(10));
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('123', '10');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('123', '20');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('123', '30');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('123', '40');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('456', '20');
```

**Solution, if you know you got 4 plants**

```
SELECT MATERIAL
FROM TEST
GROUP BY MATERIAL
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PLANT) = 4
```

**Solution, if you don't know the number of plants**

```
SELECT MATERIAL
FROM TEST
GROUP BY MATERIAL
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PLANT) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PLANT) FROM TEST)
```

Comment: exactly. Thanks Mathias.  i appreciate for the time you have worked on it and for solution.